# I can't find how to change the color of a text depending on an element on another branch

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to change the color of the text in the "catalog-stats" element to #ff3546 when a gif file is found at "fileThumb"

```
<div id="t01234567" class="thread catalog-thread" style="--tn-w: 250; --tn-h: 225.90361445783134;">
<div id="pc01234567" class="postContainer catalog-container" data-full-i-d="gif.01234567">
<div id="p01234567" class="post catalog-post">
<div id="f01234567" class="file">
<div id="fT01234567" class="fileText"><span class="file-info"><a href="https://link.url/image.gif" target="_blank"><span class="fnswitch"><span class="fntrunc">0oa0d4o3b2c3e5e5d21a93(...).gif</span><span class="fnfull">0oa0d4o3b2c3e5e5d21a93.gif</span></span></a> (1.3 MB, 457x413)</span><span class="fileText-original">File: <a title="08a0ad3bb26c38e5be5d21a93332aec41.gif" href="https://link.url/image.gif" target="_blank">0oa0d4o3b2c3e5e5d21a93(...).gif</a> (1.3 MB, 457x413)</span> <a class="sauce" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a> </div>
<a class="fileThumb" href="https://link.url/image.gif" target="_blank"><img style="height: 225px; width: 249px;" src="//link.url/image.jpg" alt="1.3 MB" data-md5="m7oQ/V47u8X07T8TnlOF48w27CA==" /></a></div>
<a class="catalog-link" href="/image.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="catalog-thumb" style="width: 150px; height: 135.542px;" src="https://link.url/image.jpg" alt="" data-width="249" data-height="225" /></a>
<div class="werkTyme-filename">04aop0do7b2c835e82t1a3.gif</div>
<div class="catalog-stats"><span title="Posts / Files / Page"><span class="post-count">71</span> / <span class="file-count">36</span> / <span class="page-count">2</span></span></div>
<div id="pi01234567" class="postInfo desktop"><input name="01234567" type="checkbox" value="delete" /> <span class="nameBlock"><span class="name">Anonymous</span> </span> <span class="dateTime" title="01/02/03(Wed)00:01:02" data-utc="1677049639">1 days ago</span> <span class="postNum desktop"><a title="Link to this post" href="/image/01234567#p01234567">No.</a><a title="Reply to this post" href="/image/01234567#q01234567">24602197</a> <span class="page-num" title="This thread is on page 2 in the original index.">[2]</span> [<a class="replylink" href="/image/01234567" target="_blank">Reply</a>]</span></div>
<blockquote id="m01234567" class="postMessage">Exemple text 1</blockquote>
<div class="catalog-replies">
<div class="catalog-reply"><time data-utc="1677156527003" data-abbrev="1">8h</time>: <a class="catalog-reply-excerpt" href="/image/01234567#p05687886">Exemple text 2.</a><a class="catalog-reply-preview" href="/image/01234567#p05687886">...</a></div>
<div class="catalog-reply"><time data-utc="1687163395100" data-abbrev="1">6h</time>: <a class="catalog-reply-excerpt" href="/image/01234567#p24713340">Exemple text 3</a><a class="catalog-reply-preview" href="/image/01234567#p24713340">...</a></div>
<div class="catalog-reply"><time data-utc="1677975923000" data-abbrev="1">3h</time>: <a class="catalog-reply-excerpt" href="/image/01234567#p34671310">Exemple text 4</a><a class="catalog-reply-preview" href="/image/01234567#p34671310">...</a></div>
<div class="catalog-reply"><time data-utc="1447178478000" data-abbrev="1">2h</time>: <a class="catalog-reply-excerpt" href="/image/01234567#p04611994">Exemple text 5</a><a class="catalog-reply-preview" href="/image/01234567#p04611994">...</a></div>
<div class="catalog-reply"><time data-utc="1677180237000" data-abbrev="1">32m</time>: <a class="catalog-reply-excerpt" href="/image/01234567#p34618871">Exemple text 6</a><a class="catalog-reply-preview" href="/image/01234567#p34618871">...</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    const catalogThreads = document.getElementsByClassName('catalog-thread');
    for (let thread of catalogThreads) {
        const webms = thread.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".gif"]');
        if (webms.length > 0) {
            const catalogStats = thread.querySelector('.catalog-stats');
            catalogStats.style.backgroundColor = '#ff3546';
        }
    }
})();
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  const catalogStats = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog-stats');
  catalogStats.forEach(stats => {
    const fileThumb = stats.closest('.thread').querySelector('.fileThumb');
    if (fileThumb && fileThumb.href.endsWith('.gif')) {
      stats.style.color = '#ff3546';
    }
  });
})();
```

but it didn't change anything, I don't know much about it enough so I don't know at all if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: You can do this will some simple CSS and without any JavaScript. Does the catalogStats element always appear after fileThumb?

Comment: yes it always appears after, and I really wish I could do it in javascript

Comment: Your first JavaScript solution works correctly.  Yet, you need to make a small change to wait until the page has finished loading. See this [working example of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/oc9xyp6m/show).